# How to disable only header (not footer) for page with customized chapter heading?

Tags: memoir, fancyhdr

Here is the minimal code on which I am working. Can the header action be postponed to next page. And clear the header only.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[text={4.1in,6.75in}]{geometry}
\DisemulatePackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%central footer; for page numbers in footer
\cfoot{\thepage}

%header for even page 
\fancyhead[CE]{\small गीताशास्त्रोपदेशसोपानपङ्क्तिः}

\newcommand\sopaana[1]{%customized chapter heading
{
\fancyhead[CO]{\small #1} %header for odd page
{\bfseries\large #1 }
}
}

\begin{document}

\sopaana{३. दैवासुरसंपद् विभागः}

६. लोकेऽस्मिन् जायमाना मनुष्या द्विप्रकाराः - दैवसंपद्युक्ता आसुरसंपद्युक्ताश्चेति।

\end{document}
```

Here is the output
[image: output]

Comment: I think you should add `\thispagestyle{plain}` to your customized sectioning command. BTW: `memoir` has it's own built-in header/footer features. You should use them.

Comment: using `\thispagestyle{plain}` is doing the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\thispagestyle{plain}` in my code solved the problem

`\newcommand\sopaana[1]{%customized chapter heading
{\thispagestyle{plain}\fancyhead[CO]{\small #1} %header for odd page
{\bfseries\large #1 }}}`

This what memoir manual says:

> **plain** The header is empty and the folio (page number) is centered at the bottom of the page.

Comment: plus you should not use `fancyhdr` in connection to memoir.